# StoreModule.forFeature does not exist

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

Im trying to take an existing ngrx Store State and refactor it into sub feature modules.The problem is when I'm using StoreModule.forFeature in my feature modules imports... I get an error during compile:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/components/login/login.module.ts:67:21
TS2339: Property 'forFeature' does not exist on type 'typeof StoreModule'.
```

I have actually searched the node_modules/@ngrx/store for "forFeature" which yielded no results. I then re-installed both  @ngrx/store & @ngrx/core, still getting no search results for 'forFeature'. I checked the documentation and 'forFeature' is still listed, not depracted, at list in the docs.

The importing statements are as follows:

```
import {StoreModule} from "@ngrx/store";
import {reducers} from "./rdx/reducers/index"; ...
@NgModule({
imports: [StoreModule.forFeature('loginFeature',reducers)]
...
}
```

the versions im using o NGRX as shown in the package json are as follows:

```
"@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
"@ngrx/store": "^2.2.3",
```

Also searched google for this issue with no result. only results for for the depration of "forRoot" to "provideStore" which I already use.

Comment: There can only be one stotre, plain and simple

Comment: Im talking about the StoreModule.forFeature() method as explained in the post. this method is how they explain abstracting the store into modules, its in their documentation, yet it does not exist in the defenitions of StoreModule in the node_modules libraries.

Comment: Sounds like your version of ngrx is too old. The current stable version is 5.2. It is hard to tell when they introduced fractal state. It is at least present by v4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this issue.
The problems waere:

1. that when I installed ngrx it automatically installed the latest of the previous versions of ngrx meaning **2.2.3**, to install the really latest I had to use **npm install --save @ngrx/store@latest @ngrx/core@latest** which installed **"@ngrx/store": "^5.2.0"**
2. The documentation of ngrx - in their github documentation they instruct you to specifically install ngrx like so:
   **npm install @ngrx/core @ngrx/store@2.2.3 --save**, you can see this in the following link under instalation: https://github.com/ngrx/store

Answer (score 0):

There is something else wrong with your code.

The error does not say "Property 'forFeature' does not exist on type StoreModule"

It says "Property 'forFeature' does not exist on type TYPEOF StoreModule" (which should be undefined).

Comment: but im using the store everywhere else in my code with no issues only when I tried to use forFeature that i got this error

Comment: I think it has something to do with ngrx version then. Why are you using v2.0 if there is v5.2 available now? Documentation is probably referencing the new version. Try updating your dependancy.

Comment: yes you were right... its the version. however for my deffence in the defult documentation of ngrx store they instruct you to install the 2.2 version specifically while in the platform page they use instructions for 4.x versions